# Chaining promisses with Webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

first, let me make point ouy that I'm new to node.js and asynchronous programming, so my code may is probably really bad. I am trying to build a webscraper using webdriverio and cheerio. In this webscraper I must make a query, scrape the results of the query while moving between pages of content and pages of results, and then  perform a new query after the results were exhausted. This is the code I have come up with so far (assume that the client has already been initiated and the function "make_new_query()" is being called from a ".then()" action):

```
function scrapt_content(){
// if array of content links is exhausted -> move to next page or perform new query
if(contents_pointer == contents.length){
    
    return client.isExisting("li.next-page > a").then(function(isExisting){
        // if there is a link to a a new page of results -> move to new page
        if(isExisting){
            return change_pages();
        } else {
            return make_new_query();
        };
    });

// change to new and scrapt it
} else {

    // var parsed = cheerio.load(res);
    ... scrap content using cherio ...
    .
    .
    .
    contents_pointer++;

    return scrapt_content(); 

    })
};
};

function change_pages(){

client
    .click("li.next-page > a")
    .getAttribute("h2 a", "href");
    .then(function(res){
        contents_pointer = 0;
        news_links = res;
        return scrapt_content();
    })
}

function make_new_query(){
.
.
.
client.url(new_query_url)
    .getAttribute("h2 > a", "href")
    .then(function(res){
        content_links = res;
        return scrapt_content();
    })
}
}
```

The problem is that after getting to the first page of content to scrape (the code performs the query and enters this page which the first link in the array of content_links), the webdriver closes. It is like the code performs first the function change_pages, which calls scrapt_content and than terminates prematurely. So, I'm assuming the error while chaining actions is in this function. Can anyone point out my mistakes while trying to chain these actions?

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing some code because I can't tell at which point you are closing the webdriver. However, you need to use a promise to assure that the function doesn't return before the async operations are complete. Since you are in node you have most ES6 features built in so you can add "use strict" at the very top line of your code (to enable ES6 features) and then just do this (for example with your scrapt_content function:

```js
//this function returns a promise
function scrapt_content(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    InsertyourAsyncFunctionHere().then(function(){
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

//setting promise resolve/reject callbacks with then and catch
scrapt_content.then(function(){
  //resolve (success) callback content here
}).catch(function(err){
  //reject (error) callback contenthere
  console.log(err.message)
});
```